# Iterating through record fields

Tags: iteration, record, elm

In Elm, one of my records (the `type alias` construct) have a lot of entries, and I was wondering if there's a built-in way to iterate through it. Either directly or by converting it to a `Dict`

So I was thinking something like:

```
let
  myRecord = MyRecord ...
  showEntry key value = ...
in
  map showEntry myRecord
```

Thanks for your time!

### Update

To answer the questions about the actual data, I have 12 fields of the same type. The 12 fields are all required to have that exact name, hence the record type and not a `Dict`. Whether it's named as a string in a record or a type in itself doesn't matter, as long as I can uniquely identify that value from the other 11. In code the record looks something like:

```
type alias InnerType { value : Int, ... }

type alias Record = { inner1 : InnerType, inner2 : InnerType, ... }
```

Since all the fields in the record have the same type, I just wanted to see if there's an easier way to go through them instead of naming all 12. Unless there's a better way to represent this, in which case I'm all ears! :-)

Comment: in short, no. Such data needs to be modelled as a Dict in the first place. The reason being that you could have a record of a String and an Int, but no 1 function could operate on the values

Comment: I suggest you to give us a little more information about actual data you want to represent.  We may be able to come up with better data model.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! You have a great point about the types @SimonH, so that wouldn't really make sense. But then Tosh's point about representation might be relevant. I haven't worked too much with Elm, so there's probably a better way to solve this. I updated the question to explain exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your record will *only* ever have twelve elements and you don't mind sacrificing a little verbosity in your type definition for type safety ([make impossible states impossible!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcgmSRJHu_8)), you could start with enumeration of those twelve indexes:

```elm
type Index
    = Inner1
    | Inner2
    ...
    | Inner12
```

You could redefine `Record` to a `type` instead of a record type alias:

```elm
type Record =
    Record
        InnerType
        InnerType
        -- repeat InnerType 12 times
```

Now you can create a few convenience functions for getting and setting values in a type-safe manner:

```elm
get : Index -> Record -> InnerType
get i (Record i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12) =
    case i of
        Inner1 -> i1
        Inner2 -> i2
        ...
        Inner12 -> i12

set : Index -> InnerType -> Record -> Record
set i val (Record i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12) =
    case i of
        Inner1 -> Record val i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12
        Inner2 -> Record i1 val i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12
        ...
        Inner12 -> Record i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 val
```

And you can create a list from your record like this:

```elm
toList : Record -> List InnerType
toList (Record i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12) =
    [ i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12 ]
```

As you can see, this gets verbose, but it's only in the definition of the Record type that it becomes verbose. If you confine all this code to a `Record` module, then accessing and modifying records is clean, concise, and more importantly, type safe. You are not subject to a Dictionary where a key may not exist, or a List or Array where an index might not exist. Your Record type would be sealed up nice and tight, at the expense of a little verbosity in the definition.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/9c7d65f540d0eb6de073c08522bf1efd) containing the full definition.

Comment: I actually really like this definition. As you say it's completely type-safe. And can actually be extended to things like lists... Nice, thank you for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a `List` (or an `Array`) of `InnerType`, as you said the structure itself is fixed at 12 of these. As for iterating, here's the example for json encoding a list of `InnerType`

```
inners 
  |> List.indexedMap (\idx inner -> ("inner" ++ toString idx, encodeInner inner))
  |> Json.Encode.object
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon, that actually sounds reasonable. It's a shame I can't get them named, but if they're ordered by convention it should be the same.

Comment: what is your tuple `("inner" ++ toString idx, encodeInner inner)` doing there?  so you return a tuple?  what does that ultimately return back up?